# Gitlab runner - fatal: repository 'http://gitlab.dev.pl/user/repo-name.git/' not found

Tags: git, dns, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have just installed ubuntu server 18.04 on my virtual machine and setup Gitlab. I have problem with DNS and i connect to it with IP address.

I have issue with GitLab CI Runner -> I have got error `fatal: repository 'http://gitlab.dev.pl/user/repo-name.git/' not found`

I have no problem cloning and pushing to git from server and outside of it.

Whole Job log:

```
 Running with gitlab-runner 13.1.1 (6fbc7474)
  on things-keeper-runner _VcemHSn
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 ...
Pulling docker image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 ...
Using docker image sha256:006ded9ddf293ffe62ff192776bcb783199ca608405983cf53e2ea8099d3d786 for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 ...
Preparing environment
00:02
Running on runner-vcemhsn-project-1-concurrent-0 via dev_server...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/user/repo-name/.git/
fatal: repository 'http://gitlab.dev.pl/user/repo-name.git/' not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1

stages:
    - build
    - test

before_script:
    - "cd src"
    - "dotnet restore"

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - "dotnet build"

test:
    stage: test
    script: 
        - "cd .."
        - "dotnet test"
```

Probably runner can not resolve git.dev.pl correctly. Can i check it somehow or pass ip address?
Can you please help me resolve my issue?

Comment: You need to provide way more information. Your post not even contains a question.

Comment: I missclicked publishing question before finishing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to documentation [benji-over-9000-benchonaut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11993317/benji-over-9000-benchonaut) provided I was able to solve the problem.

I needed to add one row into /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

```
clone_ulr = "http//192.168.0.32/"
```

Answer (score 0):

- this is not DNS, a DNS error shows warnings like NXDOMAIN or "domain not found"
  **update:** Next time please mention that your gitlab instance is not publicly viewable
- when you open https://gitlab.dev.pl/ -> **THERE IS NO GITLAB INSTANCE** , also the certificate is invalid ( which would prevent you from checking out anyway)
- Gitlab returns "Not found" also when you are not authorized , so **use SSH key** or get a token and then use the url https://username:token@gitlab.some.org:4443/username/repo-name/
- better deploy https on your gitlab instance under any circumstance

Comment: I have set gitlab on virtual machine, so it is not visible from outside of my local network.

Comment: the gitlab runner will use docker DNS subsystem , so if your **sure** that the location is correct ( e.g. bare git clone works ) , you might have to adjust the dns settings of it https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html